# Floating point literals

Tags: z3

I've two questions regarding writing IEEE floating-point constants, as accepted by Z3's FPA logics:

First, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181211/qf-fpa-does-z3-support-ieee-754-arithmetic), Christoph used the example:

```
 ((_ asFloat 11 53) roundTowardZero 0.5 0))
```

I'm wondering what the final `0` signifies? I've tried:

```
 ((_ asFloat 11 53) roundTowardZero 0.5))
```

And that seems to work as well. Rummer's [paper](http://www.philipp.ruemmer.org/publications/smt-fpa.pdf) doesn't seem to require the final 0 either; so I'm curious what role it plays.

Second, when I get a model from Z3, it prints floating-point literals like so:

```
 (as +1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625p1 (_ FP 11 53))
```

How do I interpret the `p1` suffix? What other suffixes are possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing these issues out. Both of them are because there is no agreed upon standard for floating-point literals in the input or output yet.

The final `0` in the example represents the (binary) exponent, i.e., `(... 0.5 1) == 1.0`. We added this simply because numbers sometimes would require a lot of space if the exponent cannot be specified separately. This way, we can often specify them quite succinctly.

The `p1` suffix in the output represents the binary exponent, i.e., where `e8` means `10^8`, the suffix `p8` would mean `2^8`. Z3 currently uses only binary exponents, so there would always be a p-suffix here, but this may change in the future. The rest of the number is given enough decimal digits to represent a precise result.

Note that the output format is not agreed upon yet by the SMT community. This may change in the future. For instance, there are discussions about whether this should be done in IEEE bit-vector format or an intermediate format that lies somewhere between reals and non-IEEE bit-vectors.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, that makes sense. Reading Rummer's paper, however, I was left with the understanding that FP numerals should be written using rationals, like so: `(/ 2 3)`. This can be used in both as inputs an in the models. I like this approach as it is unambiguous, and every FP number can be converted to a rational with relative ease. Maybe we can have a `pp.print_fpa_as_rational` or a similar option to specify this to bring some consistency for tools that are built on top of Z3?

Comment: Yes, Z3 also accepts rationals here, e.g., ((_ asFloat 11 53) roundTowardZero (/ 2 3)). Personally, I prefer the mantissa+exponent notation because it is often more succinct, but others may of course have other preferences. Before implementing different options for the output, I'd like to wait a little to see what the SMT community decides upon (e.g., we had requests for IEEE bit-vector format in the output too).

Comment: A note for everybody who is interested in FPA in SMT: There is a google group called smt-fp [see http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/smt-fp] which is used for discussions regarding this topic, including of course the output format. Feedback and requests are most welcome there!